# Keras how to slice output of a layer and then add it to the model

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have a layer which outputs [N,100,100,2]

I want to use only the [N,100,100,0], I have used slice(layer,[0,0,0,0],[-1,-1,-1,1] to get this, however I am unable to add this sliced output to a model as it is not a layer.

How is it done.

Can some one provide a code snippet.

```
c3 = Convolution2D(2, (1, 1),strides=(1,1),padding='same',use_bias=True,activation='softmax')
output = (c3)(output)
slicedoutput = slice(output,[0,0,0,0],[-1,-1,-1,1])
classifier = Model(inputs=[image_a],outputs=[slicedoutput,outputboxes])
```

Comment: What have you tried? post your relevant code.

Comment: Edited to include relevant portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inbuilt slice layer in Keras. But you can use Lambda layer for your purpose.

In your case instead of using slice from `keras.backend` you can use Lambda layer

```
slicedoutput = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,:,0])(output)
```

Comment: I am new to Keras , can you be kind enough to explain how to implement it. I am unable to find any clear documentation for dummies. is X a separate function? If so can the slice function be called inside it?

Comment: `output` will be taken as x and it will return `x[:,:,:,0]`. Here x is just a variable name. For more info you can search for python's Lamba expression/function. It works in similar way.